# NetSuite: ClientScript Issue

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to add a new custom selection in SO.
So I've developed a UserEvent Script and ClientScript.
All work well in sandbox.
But it's not working in production.
UserEvent Script works well in production, only ClientScript is not working.

```
EntryPoint.beforeLoad = (context) => {
        const LOGTITLE = "beforeload " + context.newRecord.id;
        
        try {
            if(context.form && context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
                var currentForm = context.form;
                
               currentForm.addField({
                    id: 'custpage_paymentoption',
                    type: 'SELECT',
                    label: 'Custom Payment Option',
               });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            log.error(LOGTITLE, JSON.stringify(e));
        }

        return true;
    }
```

```
EntryPoint.fieldChanged = (scriptContext) => {
        const LOGTITLE = "fieldChanged " + scriptContext.currentRecord.id;
        
        try {
            var record = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        
            if (scriptContext.fieldId == 'custpage_paymentoption') {
                var currentOption = record.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'custpage_paymentoption',
                })
                log.debug('currentOption', currentOption);

                record.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'paymentoption',
                    value: currentOption,
                    ignoreFieldChange: true,
                    forceSyncSourcing: true
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            log.error(LOGTITLE, JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    };
```

Please let me know if someone knows the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an error in the log?
Do you see the script running?
Is the script deployed?
Is the script deployed on the right record?
There is only the possibility to have a maximum 10 Client scripts on a record for the user experience.
Please check if you don't have more than 10.
After 10, the scripts will be ignored.
To solve this issue, you can add your function to an existing one to avoid having too many scripts.
You can also remove the unnecessary scripts.

Comment: thank you. Now I want to add some scripts in fieldChange() to change the current subtab in Sales Order.  Current Subtab is Item, and after I edit custom field, I want to make current subtab to Payment. Could you give me some advice?